# Select Child Control of UserControl in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, avaloniaui, avalonia

This is a general Syntax Question.

I have a UserControl

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControlTest.Views.MyControl">
            
            <StackPanel Name="StackPanel1">
                <Button Name="Button1" Content="Hello From UserControl XAML"/>
                <Button Name="Button2" Content="Hello From UserControl XAML"/>
            </StackPanel>

</UserControl>
```

And the Window

```
<Window xmlns:views="using:UserControlTest.Views"
        x:Class="UserControlTest.Views.MainWindow">

    <views:MyControl Name="MyControl1"></views:MyControl>

</Window>
```

Is there a way to select the properties of the child elements from XAML of the MainWindow like i can do in cs?

So basically im looking for an **XAML equivalent** of this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Get<UserControl>("MyControl1").Get<Button>("Button1").Content = "Hello From Window CS";
    }
}
```

What i hope for is something similar to this:

```
<Window xmlns:views="using:UserControlTest.Views"
        x:Class="UserControlTest.Views.MainWindow">

    <views:MyControl Name="MyControl1">
        <views:MyControl ??? Button1> Hello From Window XAML <views:MyControl ??? Button1>
    </views:MyControl>
</Window>
```

This is only about selecting the child from outside in XAML. This is not about setting a value which can be achieved with bindings and a propper class definition.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you could use styles and select the control you are interested in:

```
<views:MyControl>
  <views:MyControl.Styles>
    <Style Selector="Button#Button1">
      <Setter Property="Content" Value="Hello From Window XAML"/>
    </Style>
  </views:MyControl.Styles>
</views:MyControl>
```

You can read more about selectors [here](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/styling/selectors)